# How to delete text between all braces {} in vim

Tags: vim

I want to delete all text between each braces {} in file (including the braces themselves). I know command %d which deleted text between braces under cursor but I want to make it automatically for all document.

Example:
I have something like that:

```
public int getMinimum() {
    return min;
}
public void setMinimum(int min) {
    this.min= min;
}
```

I want to have something like that:

```
public int getMinimum()
public void setMinimum(int min)
```

Comment: These characters {} are called *braces*, not "branches". Though the terminology can vary (they're sometimes called "brackets"), so showing the characters themselves is a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the [global](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g) command:

`:g/{/normal f{da{`

This does: For all lines containing a `{`, move to the first* `{` on that line and delete everything from there up  to and including a matching `}`.

If you want to add a `;` at the end - which I suspect would be the next thing you'd want - you can add a `A;` at the end of that command.

Note that this might break if you have comments or strings containing {}s in your file.

---

* If the first character of that line is a `{`, and it contains *another* `{`, this will actually move to the second `{`. Unlikely to happen in this scenario, worth bearing in mind though. I think in that case you can do `f{F{`, although I'd think there should be somehow a way to jump to the nth character or something, but I don't know what that command would be.

Comment: `n|` will jump to nth charachter :)

Comment: @dNitro Yeah, but it won't jump to the nth `{` which is what's needed here.

Comment: @Cubic `nf{` will jump to nth `{`.

Comment: No, it will jump to the _next_ nth {. `1f{` won't jump to the first `{` on the line, it'll jump to the first `{` after the cursor. If your cursor happens to be on the first `{` on the line already, it'll jump to the second `{` on the line (if any).

Comment: I also tried something like that: `:g/{(.*?)}/d`  but it is not working

Comment: @Cubic, tanx for explanations; +1

Comment: @KoinArab you can't use global command as it can't catch multiline patterns; alternatively you can use substitute command: `%s/\s*{\_[^}]\{-}}/;/gc` will do the job but i think it will bitten by nested braces as it can't handle the matching ones.

Comment: Use `:g/{/normal f{d%` to delete to the matching `}`.  This is still not 100% safe, but it handles comments better than your version.  FWIW.

Comment: @SatoKatsura No it doesn't. At least it doesn't handle the edge cases that I was thinking about any better (unless you're using a plugin that ignores paren matching in comments and such, in which case my version would work too).

Comment: Yes, that depends on the `matchit` plugin, that is distributed with recent versions of Vim.  With that however, there are cases where my version works and your doesn't.  Example: `vim -u NONE -c 'set nocompatible | syntax on | runtime! macros/matchit.vim' test.c`, where `test.c` is a C file that has a comment `/* } */` inside a `{...}` block.

Answer (score 1):

Put the cursor at `{` or `}`, then `v%d`.

Comment: Questioner asked about all braces in the file however.

Answer (score 0):

How about using famous vim dot command?

```
/{
d%
```

Now use `n.` as many times as u need it.
Still want to automate? Record macro:

```
qqn.q
99@q
```

So full sequence would be:`/{<cr>d%qqn.q99@q`
Why this way? Because it's intuitive and it's totally the vim way to do that and you can adapt it to any situation.